# 422 Error: Python POST Request

Tags: c#, python, json, mongodb, unity-game-engine

Im trying to do a **POST** request to my Rest API which is using Eve as the framework, however whenever I try to **POST** my **JSON** I get a 422 Error saying unprocessable entity. My **GET** Requests work perfectly fine. Here is my schema for my Eve App:

```
schema = {
    '_update': {
        'type': 'datetime',
        'minlength': 1,
        'maxlength': 40,
        'required': False,
        'unique': True,
    },
    'Name': {
        'type': 'string',
        'minlength': 1,
        'maxlength': 40,
        'required': True,
        'unique': False,
    },
    'FacebookId': {
        'type': 'integer',
        'minlength': 1,
        'maxlength': 40,
        'required': True,
        'unique': True,
    },
    'HighScore': {
        'type': 'integer',
        'minlength': 1,
        'maxlength': 40,
        'required': True,
        'unique': False,
    },
}
```

Here is the **JSON** I am trying to post:

```
{"_updated":null,"Name":"John Doe","FacebookId":"12453523434324123","HighScore":15}
```

Here is how I am attempting to do the **POST** request from my client:

```
IDictionary dict = Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(result.RawResult) as IDictionary;
string name = dict["name"].ToString();
string id = dict["id"].ToString();

Player player = new Player();
player.FacebookId = id;
player.Name = name;
player.HighScore = (int) GameManager.Instance.Points;

// Using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(player);

var headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"Content-Type", "application/json"}};

string url = "http://server.com/Players";
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
// Using Unity3d WWW class
WWW www = new WWW(url, encoding.GetBytes(json), headers);
StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you make it so complicated. at first you need a helper method in order to call your service. something like this:

```
private static T Call<T>(string url, string body)
{
    var contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    request.Timeout = 60 * 1000;
    request.ContentLength = contentBytes.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = @"application/json";

    using (var requestWritter = request.GetRequestStream())
        requestWritter.Write(contentBytes, 0, (int)request.ContentLength);

    var responseString = string.Empty;
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
}
```

then simply call it like this:

```
var url = "http://server.com/Players";
var output=Call<youroutputtype>(url, json);
```

note: i didn't know what is your output type so i just leave it to you.